# I am trying to get label names array for visualization and I need to run below code but run into problem. Could you guys advise me on below?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, utf-8, decode

I am trying to get label names array for visualization and I need to run below code but run into problem. Could someone please help with this error ?

My Code:

```
!pip install numpy==1.16.1
import numpy as np

label_names_array = np.chararray(3, itemsize = 4).decode("utf-8")

for key, value in label_names.items():
  label_names_array[key] = value
label_names_array
```

---

Outcome:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-044ac95aa7ba> in <module>()
      2 #import numpy as np
      3 
----> 4 label_names_array = np.chararray(3, itemsize = 4).decode("utf-8")
      5 
      6 for key, value in label_names.items():

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/defchararray.py in decode(a, encoding, errors)
    562     """
    563     return _to_string_or_unicode_array(
--> 564         _vec_string(a, object_, 'decode', _clean_args(encoding, errors)))
    565 
    566 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte
```

---

Any help appreciated. Thanks .
formatt

Comment: After initialising a chararray, it's filled with random (?) values. There's no good reason to assume that these values are interpretable as UTF-8 text. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to apply the `decode` function to the `value` you're assigning inside the loop, perhaps?

Comment: Hi, I am going to use the label_names_array in the confusion matrix as index and column + Classification matrix however when I run above code it gives an error. I am not sure how to fix it.